# TFS: Stop Team Build process has updated the Fixed In field messages

Tags: team-foundation-server

We have an interesting situation. Our build server seems to want to go back to previously closed work items and update the Integration Build field.

I understand the build server setting it the first time. I could even understand it updating that field in the event that the first build didn't complete successfully.

However, I can't understand why it continues to update all of the previously closed work items with a new Fixed In Build value.

It's very annoying to get an email about all of the closed work items for every. single. build. that I had created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your builds all successful or are they just partially successful?  When a build completes it will calculate the changes between the last successful build and the current one.  It will then update any work items that were associated to the check-ins included in the build, regardless of their current state.  Therefore if a developer associates a check-in with a closed work item then it will be included.  If your builds are just partially successful (i.e. code compiles but unit tests fail) then the next build will have the work items calculated since the last good build.

If you want, you can change the behavior so that no work items are updated as part of the build - however I suspect that is not want you want in this case.  But if you do want to stop work item creation completely then simply add the following property to your TFS2008 TFSBuild.proj file inside a

```
<SkipWorkItemCreation>true</SkipWorkItemCreation>
```

Comment: I found that one of the builds which uses that code was only partially succeeding.  Once that build started completely succeeding the emails stopped.  I guess the bigger issue is that TFS (in my mind) should NOT update the Integration Build value unless there is total success.  At this point, I'm going to completely turn off TFS's automatic update of that field and handle it myself in powershell.  Another option (for the TFS team) would be to just go ahead and create a new tab for Notes.  That way our back and forth communication on the work item isn't lost in all the update noise.